# Need help with construction of a plot

Tags: plotting

This is probably a very elementary question, but how can I construct a plot that looks like this in Mathematica:

[image]

More specifically, I am having trouble with making the y-axis with three ticks like in the figure.

Comment: The hand-drawn picture does not supply sufficient information for anyone to formulate and answer. It is not even very readable. Please edit the question to include the code you have written and the data you plotted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
ListLinePlot[{
  {{0, 25}, {1, 200}, {2, 200}},
  {{2, 200}, {3, 0}, {4, 200}, {5, 200}, {6, 0}, {7, 200}}
  },
 Axes -> False,
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
 FrameLabel -> {"Time (s)", "T (\[Degree]C)"},
 FrameStyle -> Black,
 FrameTicks -> {{{{0, 0, {0.015, 0}}, {25, 25, {0.015, 0}}, {200, 
      "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(m + 10\)]\)", {0.015, 0}}}, 
    None}, {None, None}},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, {ColorData[97][1], Dashed}},
 Epilog -> {
   Text["1 min", {#, 205}] & /@ {1.5, 4.5},
   Text[Rotate["\[Beta] = 30 K/min", 77 Degree], {#, 100}] & /@ {3.35,
      6.35},
   Text[Rotate["\[Beta] = 30 K/min", -77 Degree], {#, 
       100}] & /@ {2.35, 5.35}
   }
 ]
```

[image: Attempt at creating OP's graph.]

The main points are:

- I specified the specific tick marks to be shown using `FrameTicks`. If you prefer to use `Axes` rather than `Frame`, you would just use `Ticks`.
- To create the two different styles (solid and dashed), I created two different datasets and gave them different styling with `PlotStyle`, but there are many other ways to do this as well. You could even use `Graphics` instead of `Plot` and create the curves using `Line`.
- I added the labels to the plot using `Epilog`.

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted or not. Hopefully it's enough to get you started, but if you were looking for something different, you'll need to add some more details.